# Difference between double quotes and single quotes in Rust

Tags: rust

I was doing the adventofcode of 2020 day 3 in Rust to train a little bit because I am new to Rust and I my code would not compile depending if I used single quotes or double quotes on my "tree" variable

the first code snippet would not compile and throw the error: expected `u8`, found `&[u8; 1]`

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let text: String = fs::read_to_string("./data/text").unwrap();
    let vec: Vec<&str> = text.lines().collect();
    let vec_vertical_len = vec.len();
    let vec_horizontal_len = vec[0].len();

    let mut i_pointer: usize = 0;
    let mut j_pointer: usize = 0;
    let mut tree_counter: usize = 0;

    let tree = b"#";
    loop {
        i_pointer += 3;
        j_pointer += 1;
        if j_pointer >= vec_vertical_len {
            break;
        }

        let i_index = i_pointer % vec_horizontal_len;
        let character = vec[j_pointer].as_bytes()[i_index];
        if character == tree {
           tree_counter += 1
        }
    }

    println!("{}", tree_counter);
}
```

the second snippet compiles and gives the right answer..

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let text: String = fs::read_to_string("./data/text").unwrap();
    let vec: Vec<&str> = text.lines().collect();
    let vec_vertical_len = vec.len();
    let vec_horizontal_len = vec[0].len();

    let mut i_pointer: usize = 0;
    let mut j_pointer: usize = 0;
    let mut tree_counter: usize = 0;

    let tree = b'#';
    loop {
        i_pointer += 3;
        j_pointer += 1;
        if j_pointer >= vec_vertical_len {
            break;
        }

        let i_index = i_pointer % vec_horizontal_len;
        let character = vec[j_pointer].as_bytes()[i_index];
        if character == tree {
           tree_counter += 1
        }
    }

    println!("{}", tree_counter);
}
```

I did not find any reference explaining what is going on when using single or double quotes..can someone help me?

Comment: See https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-character-type: *the `char` literal is specified with single quotes, as opposed to string literals, which use double quotes.*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer is it works similarly to java. Single quotes for characters and double quotes for strings.

```rust
let a: char = 'k';
let b: &'static str = "k";
```

The `b''` or `b""` prefix means take what I have here and interpret as byte literals instead.

```rust
let a: u8 = b'k';
let b: &'static [u8; 1] = b"k";
```

The reason strings result in references is due to how they are stored in the compiled binary. It would be too inefficient to store a string constant inside each method, so strings get put at the beginning of the binary in header area. When your program is being executed, you are taking a reference to the bytes in that header (hence the static lifetime).

Going further down the rabbit hole, single quotes technically hold a codepoint. This is essentially what you might think of as a character. So a Unicode character would also be considered a single codepoint even though it may be multiple bytes long. A codepoint is assumed to fit into a `u32` or less  so you can safely convert any `char` by using `as u32`, but not the other way around since not all `u32` values will match valid codepoints. This also means `b'\u{x}'` is not valid since `\u{x}` may produce characters that will not fit within a single byte.

```rust
// U+1F600 is a unicode smiley face
let a: char = '\u{1F600}';
assert_eq!(a as u32, 0x1F600);
```

However, you might find it interesting to know that since Rust strings are stored as UTF-8, codepoints over 127 will occupy multiple bytes in a string despite fitting into a single byte on their own. As you may already know, UTF-8 is simply a way of converting codepoints to bytes and back again.

```rust
let foo: &'static str = "\u{1F600}";
let foo_chars: Vec<char> = foo.chars().collect();
let foo_bytes: Vec<u8> = foo.bytes().collect();
    
assert_eq!(foo_chars.len(), 1);
assert_eq!(foo_bytes.len(), 4);

assert_eq!(foo_chars[0] as u32, 0x1F600);
assert_eq!(foo_bytes, vec![240, 159, 152, 128]);
```

Comment: “ works similarly to java” or C, or C++, or C#, or D, or Go, or…