# Python like b-string concatenation in rust

Tags: python, rust, concatenation, byte

I am currently working on a side project where I am converting some code from python to rust.
In python, we can do something like:

Python code->

```
data = b'commit'+b' '+b'\x00'
print(data)
```

Output->

```
b'commit \x00'
```

Is there any way to achieve this in rust? As I need to concatenate some b'' and store them in a file.
Thanks in advance.

I tried using + operator but didn't work and shown error like: cannot add &[u8;6] with &[u8;1]

Comment: The [`concat_bytes!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.concat_bytes.html) macro is currently experimental.

Comment: Hi @PitaJ, I have checked that macro, but cannot use experimental features

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you are trying to do in rust? The current example only shows hard coded values, but I imagine in actuality it is a bit more complex. If it was just hard coded you could write `b"commit \0"` in rust and that would be it.

Comment: Yes @Locke, you are right, in actuality it a bit complex, there should be a result variable which will receive a b-string from another function then it goes like: data=b'commit'+b' '+str(len(result)).encode()+b'\x00'+result

Comment: Where are these bytes then used? You can likely use the `write!` macro to make the rust code more readable. For example: `write!(&mut writer, "commit {}\0", result.len())?`. The `writer`, can be a file, a `Vec<u8>`, or anything else that implements `std::io::Write`.

Comment: @Locke, in python, after obtaining the b'', I used zlib to compress it and then stored it in a file, can I do some thing here as well in rust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options for combining binary strings. However it sounds the best option for your use case is to use the `write!` macro. It lets you write bytes the same way you would use the `format!` and `println!` macros. This has the benefit of requiring no additional allocation. The `write!` macro uses UTF-8 encoding (the same as strings in Rust).

One thing to keep in mind though is that the `write!` will perform lots of small calls using the [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait. To prevent your program from slowing down due to the frequent calls to the OS when writing files you will want to buffer your data using a `BufWriter`.

As for zlip this is defiantly doable. In Rust, the most popular library for handling deflate, gzip, and zlib is the [`flate2`](https://crates.io/crates/flate2) crate. Using this we can wrap a writer to do the compression inline with the rest of the writing process. This lets us save memory and keeps our code tidy.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufWriter, Write};
use flate2::write::ZlibEncoder;
use flate2::Compression;

pub fn save_commits(path: &str, results: &[&str]) -> io::Result<()> {
    // Open file and wrap it in a buffered writer
    let file = BufWriter::new(File::create(path)?);
    
    // We can then wrap the file in a Zlib encoder so the data we write will
    // be compressed with zlib as we go
    let mut writer = ZlibEncoder::new(file, Compression::best());
    
    // Write our header
    write!(&mut writer, "commit {}\0", results.len())?;
    
    // Write commit hashes
    for hash in results {
        write!(&mut writer, "{}\0", hash);
    }
    
    // This step is not required, but it lets us propogate the error instead of
    // letting the final bytes buffered in the BufferedWriter from being flushed
    // when it gets dropped.writer is dropped.
    writer.by_ref().flush()?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

Additionally, you may find it helpful to read this answer to learn more about how binary strings work in Rust: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231883/5987669