# How to change var in for loop?

Tags: rust

[Problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5556282156230d0e5e000089/train/rust)
Source code:

```
fn main() {
    let dna="GCAT";
    let mut asString=String::from(dna);
    unsafe{
        let bytes = asString.as_bytes_mut();
        for byte in bytes{
            if byte==&b"T"[0]{*byte=b"U"[0];println!("H")}
        }
    }
    println!("{}",dna);
}
```

It doesn't change **T** byte for some reason. How do I suppose to do that and what's wrong in this code?

Comment: Why do you use `unsafe` when you can instead work with bytes?

Comment: This is unsafe because Strings in Rust are assumed to be valid UTF8. If you instead used a `char` iterator you could avoid the unsafe code. Also, you can rewrite `byte == &b"T"[0]` as `*byte = b'T'`. You can read more about the difference between strings, chars, and bytes at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231883/5987669

Comment: @Locke `chars()` cannot be used to mutate the string. But `Vec<u8>` can be used instead of `String`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, that is why I was suggesting a `char` iterator. He can do `dna.chars().map(|x| ... ).collect::<String>()`.

Answer (score 2):

You printed `dna`. This is an immutable string literal. It cannot change.

If you would print `asString`, you would see it has changed.

Answer (score -2):

```
println!("{}",**asString**);
```