# How can I copy a u8 slice into a u32 slice?

Tags: rust, slice

When you have two slices of the same type (and length!), Rust provides the [copy_from_slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) function to copy from one to the other.

But if my source slice is a `&[u8]` and my target slice is a `&[u32]`, is there any simpler way to copy it than manually iterating? Because there's no chance of the source values being out of range I thought there might be, but I can't find one.

```
fn copy(source: &[u8], target: &mut [u32]) {
    for (i, &ch) in source.iter().enumerate() {
        target[i] = ch as u32;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do with `zip()`, but otherwise this is the way.

Comment: You can also use https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.set_from, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is about as good as you are going to get. Most of the other solutions are going to require just as much code as this. For example, you could turn it into an iterator chain to try to improve readability. That being said, the original was already quite readable, so this isn't much of an improvement.

```rust
fn copy(source: &[u8], target: &mut [u32]) {
    source
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .map(u32::from)
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(index, value)| target[index] = value);
}
```

Or as @ChayimFriedman mentioned, you could use [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools)'s [`set_from`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.set_from). Here is what that would look like:

```rust
fn copy(source: &[u8], target: &mut [u32]) {
    target.iter_mut().set_from(source.iter().map(|x| *x as u32));
}
```

Alternatively, you could also choose to make the function generic. However, at its core it is the same thing so I'm not sure if you really gain any readability from doing this.

```rust
fn copy_into_slice_from<A, B>(src: &[A], dst: &mut [B])
where
    A: Copy,
    B: From<A>,
{
    assert_eq!(src.len(), dst.len());

    src.iter()
        .copied()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(index, value)| dst[index] = B::from(value));
}
```

I suppose another option would be some sort of `map_between_slices` function to try to save on the amount of code needed while maintaining readability?

```rust
/// Ex: map_between_slices(&src, &mut dst, |x| *x as u32);
fn map_between_slices<A, B, F>(src: &[A], dst: &mut [B], mut func: F)
where
    F: for<'a> FnMut(&'a A) -> B,
{
    assert_eq!(src.len(), dst.len());

    src.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(index, value)| dst[index] = func(value));
}
```

Comment: I assume that I'd have to do the same to convert a &[char] into a &[u32]? (To convert a string into UTF-32.)

Comment: @curiousdannii In rust a `char` is not a byte, as not all characters fit into a single byte. The second half of this answer explains a bit more on how chars/strings work in Rust: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231883/5987669 That being said, you are correct that this could be use with very few changes.

Comment: Yes I know, I can get a `&[char]` through `str.chars().collect()`. I've been looking but haven't found any nicer way turn a string into a `&[u32]`, probably because everyone wants to avoid UTF-32. But this is an old C API I'm porting so I can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in answers to [Efficiency: arrays vs pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305770/efficiency-arrays-vs-pointers) using `zip` instead of `enumerate` and manual indexing will be more efficient if the compiler is not able to optimize the latter into the former.

```rust
fn copy(source: &[u8], target: &mut [u32]) {
    for (&value, target) in source.iter().zip(target) {
        *target = value as u32;
    }
}
```